# Visually analyze fragmentation of HDD

Tags: windows, defragmentation

Is there a program that would visually show me how fragmented my HDD is? I have two reasons to ask for such a program:

1. I want to see how bad my hard disk needs defragmentation, or if or when, it requires defragmentation.
2. I'd like to get a sense of how long defragmentation is going to take.

Here's the Microsoft Windows' defragmenter:

[image: Windows defragmenter]

And I have 3 issues with it:

1. Why is it trying to defragment my SSD's?
2. What does 2% fragmented mean? Does it need optimization? Why does it not optimize it?
3. There's no visual view of the fragmentation.

I was hoping for something like WinDirStat shows visually:

[image: WinDirStat]

Comment: You will note it uses the term ‘optimize’, not ‘defragment’ here. ‘Optimizing’ an SSD in Windows terms mostly involves telling the drive firmware which parts of the drive are not in use so that the firmware can do a better job with wear-leveling (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing) for more details on the low-level aspects of this), though it also does some actual defragmentation in particularly bad cases because the _filesystem_ needs it for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Frame challenge*

Back in the day drives were 16GB or so, visual display of fragmentation was common in defrag utilities. They could also graphically visualise as the utility bubbled the data around to make new pretty pictures - it was something to watch as it worked, I suppose - as you couldn't do anything else until it had finished.
It also became much of a 'belief' that a drive had to be constantly defragged to avoid it slowing down. That really only starts to become important if the drive is getting quite full; by which time it also becomes harder to defrag.

With a modern 1TB drive* or larger, it would take more time to  draw the sectors to screen it than it would to do the task & would still fly by too fast to see, so they abandoned that idea.
2% fragmentation on a 1TB drive would barely be a few pixels of your entire screen. Nowhere near so much 'fun' to watch.

Even before the advent of SSDs, drives & OSes were becoming smart enough to avoid a lot of fragmentation at write. They were also able to defrag in the background without interrupting the user.
Since SSDs, of course, there is now absolutely no need or use for defragging at all.

*There are something like 2 billion sectors on a 1TB drive.

Comment: No, there are practical reasons to defragment an SSD. Each individual IO operation still has a cost even if there is no seek time involved, so a smaller number of larger IO operations is still preferable for sequential access and therefore less fragmentation (up to a point) does make things faster for some workloads even on an SSD. Significant fragmentation on a mostly full SSD can also limit the effectiveness of the wear-leveling done by the firmware in some cases because the firmware has to deal with more complicated access patterns.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn - I was trying to not entangle the aspects of trim with those of an old-style defrag. Keeping it simple.

Comment: But I’m not really talking about TRIM here. Actual old-style defragmentation can have a positive impact on an SSDs performance. There’s a nontrivial difference between reading hundreds of MB of data in 4kB chunks and reading that same data in 1MB chunks even if your seek time is zero, and for most modern filesystems fewer fragments means less metadata overhead in the filesystem itself.